# Reload jList on Button clicked from new data of HashSet

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I need to reload a jList after I have added new Data to my HashSet. 
After I have filled all TextFields and press the "save" Button it creates a new jListDemo Object wich will be added to my HashSet. I have written a method that converts the HashSet into a String[] and returns the data for the jList Source.

I have a fully working example below. 
Here is the class jListDemo which is in the package gui: [Click this pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/tswCadMM).

And here is the jList GUI: [Click this pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/VVfNkbTB).

When a new Object was created I want to reload the jList with the function `fillListOwners` but I only get the following errors which you can find [on this pastebin doc](http://pastebin.com/NgCdzks3).

I hope that someone has a hint for me. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post all pertinent code here on this site, not in a link that will go bad in a week or two.

Comment: I had pasted all my code into this post but Stackoverflow told me that it was "not well formated". So i had no other choise to paste it to pastebin @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: `Stackoverflow told me that it was "not well formated".` - then fix the formatting problem and repost it.

Comment: Regarding "no choice"? This hardly makes sense when you can put in the minor effort to format it well. The site's help sections will tell you how. Many of us have firewalls preventing us from seeing links, and truthfully since you're asking volunteers to help you out, wouldn't it seem right for you to put the effort in to make it easier for us to help you?

Comment: It's up to you, but only if you seriously are in need of help.

Comment: Voting to close question.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you want to dynamically update the content of a JList. If this is the requirement then use the javax.swing.ListModel to implement the Model (the data part of MVC pattern) of the JList.